# Unable to locate php.ini file or paths to it on mac

Tags: php, macos, ini

I've just starting working on a mac so this is probably very obvious.
I've installed php, pear, and lastly pecl.

My last command was sudo pecl install mongo and am prompted to add the line extension=mongo.so to php.ini configuration.

I am unable to locate the php.ini file.  I do a quick php --ini in the CL and am told the path is /etc, /etc/php/apache2/php.ini to be exact. I've tried to unhide files and well as searching via the finder but am told these directories don't exist, even though I believe my installations were done correctly.  How can I access this etc directory, as well as others like the php5 folder so I can edit my php.ini file? Thanks.  Using Yosemite 10.10.3 and latest php packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) output to locate the loaded php.ini file (Loaded Configuration File).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm just not very familiar with OS X but realized in order to access the directory I had to goto Go on the finder and enter /private/ in order to access the etc folder.